Clean RAM cache : potential troubles?
Here is the result of free -m command on my virtual machine.
Mem : 16000 (total) 820 (used) 150 (free) 1 (shared) 15029 (buff/cache) 14840 (available)
Swap : 16383 (total) 259 (used) 16124 (free)

I think the miniconda environments and docker images overload the cache.
I am wondering if, in my case of use of my virtual machine (for data science, usage of docker images, nextflow, packages and Python environment via Miniconda), is it possible and without consequences to clean the buff/cache with the command sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches in order to recover some of the RAM because I lack space ?
Let me know if more details are needed.
Thank you

Please read: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Thank's for the reminder. I've edited the post.

Any modern OS knows to use RAM for the best purpose. Free (unused) RAM is les useful than cache. Hence, the OS will prefer to use memory for cache instead of leaving it unused. But by the nature of it, cache memory can be quickly released if needed for other purposes.
